# Mongodb , Mongoose - Cascade update of embebed ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates, cascade

As a newbie in mongodb, i find this basic situation confusing.

Due two collections: Person and Province, i decide to use the embebed model:

```
Person {
  ... ,
  province: {
     name: Alicante,
     state: Spain 
  }
}
```

Alicante is in spanish, but in spanish we have many languages and sometimes people refer to some provinces to the other and local language, like in this case, the "valenciano". So we decide to change Alicante for Alacant.

Which would be the best or more extended approach to make this update in cascade?. Do you have a collection of provinces and also an embebed one in every person? How do you sincronice this?

What i thought is to have a collection "province" with this schema:

```
province {   _id: 389034803294029430   name: "Alicante",   country: "Spain" }

person {   ... ,   
           province: {
               _id: 389034803294029430
               name: "Alicante",
               country: "Spain"   
           } 
       }
```

So when i want to change "Alicante" for "Alacant" i "manually" change this by querying and changing all the matches to "Alacant".

Is this the correct approach?, is there a "consolidated" way of doing it with mongoose.js?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Clarification: do you want to know how to write the update, or do you want advice on how to handle localization issues?